# Elements missing when iterator used in a list comprehension

Tags: python, python-2.7, iterator, list-comprehension

The following example shows different behaviour depending on whether the rightmost generator in a list comprehension is a list or an iterator. Specifically, fewer results are generated when using an iterator - I find this behaviour to be very surprising.

I'm new to Python so I guess I'm missing something obvious, but I'd be grateful for an explanation.

```
>>> import itertools
>>> xs = range(0, 5)
>>> ys = range(0, 3)
>>> zs_l = [x for x in xs if not x in ys]
>>> zs_l
[3, 4]

# Validate the contents of the iterator, and create it again
>>> zs_i = itertools.ifilterfalse(lambda x: x in ys, xs)
>>> list(zs_i)
[3, 4]
>>> list(zs_i)
[]
>>> zs_i = itertools.ifilterfalse(lambda x: x in ys, xs)

>>> [(i,z) for i in [1,2] for z in zs_l]
[(1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4)]
>>> [(i,z) for i in [1,2] for z in zs_i]
[(1, 3), (1, 4)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting [`itertools.ifilterfalse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.ifilterfalse) docs,

> **Make an iterator** that filters elements ...

Quoting python's documentation for the term [*iterator*](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-iterator),

> An object representing a stream of data. Repeated calls to the iterator’s `next()` method return successive items in the stream. **When no more data are available a `StopIteration` exception is raised instead. At this point, the iterator object is exhausted and any further calls to its `next()` method just raise `StopIteration` again.** Iterators are required to have an `__iter__()` method that returns the iterator object itself so every iterator is also iterable and may be used in most places where other iterables are accepted. One notable exception is code which attempts multiple iteration passes. **A container object (such as a `list`) produces a fresh new iterator each time you pass it to the `iter()` function or use it in a for loop. Attempting this with an iterator will just return the same exhausted iterator object used in the previous iteration pass, making it appear like an empty container.**

The bolded text above answers your questions.

When you do

```
>>> [(i,z) for i in [1,2] for z in zs_i]
[(1, 3), (1, 4)]
```

the iterator `zs_i` is exhausted in the first iteration with the for loop. So, when it used in the for loop again, the second time, as shown in the documentation above, `StopIteration` is raised. So, for loop breaks and it is not processing it again.

But the same works with the list returned by `range`, because, from the above documentation,

> A container object (such as a `list`) produces a fresh new iterator each time you pass it to the `iter()` function or use it in a for loop.

So, when you pass the list to the for loop in every iteration, it creates a new iterator and that is why it works as you expected.

Answer (score 4):

`itertools.ifilterfalse` is a generator. If you consume everything it `yield`s by calling `list` on it, it will not yield anything after that.

In

```
[(i,z) for i in [1,2] for z in zs_i]
```

`zs_id` is exhausted for `i = 1`. When `i = 2`, `zs_i` will not yield anything.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is a complement to the other answers that explain the underlying mechanisms in more detail. If you want this to work, the generator has to be recreated multiple times in the comprehension.

One way would be to initialize a new generator for each pass of the nested for-loop:

```
>>> [(i,z) for i in [1,2] for z in itertools.ifilterfalse(lambda x: x in ys, xs)]
[(1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4)]
```